# Sorting & Removing Rows in a C# Multidimension List

Tags: c#

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var trackList = new List<Track>();
        trackList.Add(new Track{ TrackID = 1234, Name = "I'm Gonna Be (500 Miles)", Artist = "The Proclaimers(I)", Album = "Finest(I)", PlayCount = 10, SkipCount = 1 });
        trackList.Add(new Track { TrackID = 5678,Name = "I'm Gonna Be (1000 Miles)",Artist = "The Proclaimers(II)",Album = "Finest(II)", PlayCount = 20,SkipCount = 2});
        trackList.Add(new Track { TrackID = 9101,Name = "I'm Gonna Be (2000 Miles)",Artist = "The Proclaimers(III)",Album = "Finest(II)", PlayCount = 40,SkipCount = 3});
        trackList.Add(new Track { TrackID = 1213,Name = "I'm Gonna Be (4000 Miles)",Artist = "The Proclaimers(IV)",Album = "Finest(IV)", PlayCount = 80,SkipCount = 4});

        //How to sort based on column name:Album 
        //something like this below.
        trackList.Sort(trackList([0 4]);

        //How to remove rows after search items in a column based on some criteria

        trackList.RemoveAll(Album => Album.Contains("(II)"));

         //How to Populate resuts in a listbox

         //listBox1.DataSource = trackList();

    }

    public class Track
    {
        public int TrackID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }
        public string Album { get; set; }
        public int PlayCount { get; set; }
        public int SkipCount { get; set; }
    }
```

1. How to sort based on column name: Album
2. Find items in a column and remove those rows.
3. Results should be placed in a listbox or may be create a new list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
trackList = trackList
    .Where(t => !t.Album.Contains("(II)"))
    .OrderBy(t => t.Album)
    .ToList();
```

By the way, it's not a multidimensional list but a `List<Track>`.

Comment: Thanks, Awesome! How to create a new List or Array with the results after the above operation.

Comment: @AAP `var newList = rackList.Where(...).ToList();`

Comment: @AAP: i'm already building a list there, look at the final `ToList()`

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter, As I understood you overwrite the same (trackList = trackList) with the filtered results?

Comment: @user3185569: Many thanks! You guys are great helpers for new learners.

Comment: @AAP: yes i do, the same as `trackList.Sort` and `trackList.RemoveAll` do :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: If I have a two dimensional Array [,] Can I use the same technique to sort and remove. Lets say(Want to sort [0,3] third column and removeAll.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: How can I use column number instead (Album) in the code '.Where(t => !t.Album.Contains("(II)"))' :-)

Comment: @AAP: i dont understand, which column-number? `Album` is a property in a class not a column.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Okay I misunderstood. Actually I thought if I have list List<string> with many rows and columns so I can use the same code as you suggested to access the say columnnumber 3 or 4 to do the same operation.